# codenameone how to reference field contents in addArgument command

Tags: codenameone

i have a form that contains several text fields and a 'register' button.

when the register button is pressed i want to send the contents of the fields to a web svc.

I have successfully connected to my webservice and passed hardcoded post variables.

I am having trouble getting the proper syntax to addArgument to pass the contents of the text fields.

For example, if I have a form (Register) and on that form i have a text field (txtFirstName),

what is the syntax to add the contents of the txtFirstName field to the addArgument command?

My code follows:

```
@Override
protected void onRegister_BtnRegisterAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) {
    // register new user
    ConnectionRequest r = new ConnectionRequest(); 
    r.setUrl("http://localhost/ihsnj/websvc.php");
    r.setPost(true);

    r.addArgument("R", "Y");    // R = register
    // this is the line generating the error <cannot find symbol>
    r.addArgument("FirstName",txtFirstName.getText());

    InfiniteProgress prog = new InfiniteProgress();
    Dialog dlg = prog.showInifiniteBlocking();
    r.setDisposeOnCompletion(dlg);
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(r);


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem isn't related to ConnectionRequest. You need to use find methods not fields since components are only constructed when the form is actually showing (to preserve RAM).

Use `findTxtFirstName(c).getText()` as the second argument e.g.:

```
req.addArgument("first_name", findTxtFirstName(c).getText());
```

Comment: I still get can not find symbol for the field. I am editing the question and adding my actual code...